# Runbooks and Azure Automation

Tags: azure

As I understand it, it's going to be possible to import runbooks into Azure Automation. Are all runbooks the same though - will I be able to import all runbooks or just SMA runbooks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can import all SMA runbooks into azure automation. Make sure you import modules if you have any custom modules